# load balancer suddenly shows slow response times

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

We have a load balancer in AWS that has been running for a while. Since last week, there has been a huge increase in response time in the metrics graphs, although this hasn't been reported by users. Many of these are logged as `-1` for their response times in the logs, which means that they got no response at all, just a 4## or 5## status code when the request times out.

In looking at the URLs for some of these failed requests, I see a few different hosts and these hosts show no sign of high mem / CPU / IO. So I'm not sure what else I can do to track down the cause of this. I've looked at every graph I can find for every server that is connected to the load balancer but I don't see any spikes that match up to when the problem started.

Is there any way to find out what is causing the load balancer response times to be so high?

Comment: Technically the ELB isn't slow to respond, your backends are. The easiest way to identify these types of issues is with APM (application performance monitoring). Some common ones are new relic, elasticsearch APM, and datadog. You can mitigate the timeouts by adjusting the idle timeout value on the ELB (default is 60 seconds)

Comment: Can you trace the requests from the ELB to your back end and log at the logs together? That will tell you if the back end or front end is slow. Correlate with app error logs and cloudwatch to look at CPU etc.

Comment: Are you using an AWS Load Balancer (NLB/ALB/ELB) or are you using a custom LB on an EC2 or something like that